# Java 6 pattern matcher performance improvements

Tags: java

I am facing one problem with Java 6 pattern matcher, I am running the matcher against a large string (10,000+ characters), the site is becoming very slow.

Is there any way to split the strings into many strings and speedup the performance using Java6.

Here is the code, the thing is that the matcher pattern is variable (blocked words)

The pattern is user defined and is a large text of 100+ words (blocked words)

```
String text = "very large text file content";
String spamRegexpDefinedByUser = "superman";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(spamRegexpDefinedByUser, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
```

Comment: It may also be that the regex is poorly written (catastrophic backtracing etc). If those are really words you are looking for, why not first split along the spaces?

Comment: as i said its simple comma separated list of blocked words, no special characters but a big list

Comment: If you can use Java 8? Is there any design limitation?

Comment: Maybe implement a trie?

Comment: If your pattern is simply a blacklist, try to refactor the code not to use pattern matching to verify that's the issue. just iterate over the list for every starting position. Remember to compare char by char using .charAt instead of .substring to avoid exploding complexity!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the solution that was not designed for such tasks. You should consider usage of [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure as @fge already mentioned. The algorithm that solves your task is called [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm).

Here are some existing implementations in Java (I've never used any of these however):

https://github.com/raymanrt/aho-corasick

https://github.com/robert-bor/aho-corasick